# PropTypes in functional component don't work and don't throw an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have the following functional footer component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; 


const FooterComp = (props)=> {

  return (
        <div>
            <span>
                created by {props.creator}
            </span>
        </div>
  );
}

FooterComp.propTypes = {
  creator: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};


export default FooterComp;
```

and I want to make sure that only a String can be passed.

This is my index.js component from where on I want to pass the props to the footer comp:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>

    <Switch>
      ....
    </Switch>
    <Footer creator={7}/>
  </HashRouter>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I give the Footer Component the number 7 it works very well. How can I make the propTypes work?

Comment: There is no error. Exactly!

Comment: Do you expect an error on the screen or in the console?

Comment: [Works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-67128596-3yb10) -- there's an error in the console as expected. (If you were expecting an error in a build step, that's not what [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) does. From the top of the npm page: *"Runtime type checking for React props and similar objects."* Note "runtime," not "build time.")

Comment: Okay it doesn´t block the execiton. I have also an error in the console.Thanks man